# Deep learning classification with no labels

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, classification, unsupervised-learning

I must participate in a research project regarding a deep learning application for classification. I have a huge dataset containing over 35000 features - these are good values, taken from laboratory.

The idea is that I should create a classifier that must tell, given a new input, if the data seems to be good or not. I must use deep learning with keras and tensor flow.

The problem is that the data is not classified. I will enter a new column with 1 for good and 0 for bad. Problem is, how can I find out if an entry is bad, given the fact that the whole training set is good?

I have thought about generating some garbage data but I don't know if this is a good idea - I don't even know how to generate it. Do you have any tips?

Answer (score 2):

I would start with anamoly detection. You can first reduce features with f.e. an (stacked) autoencoder and then use local outlier factor from sklearn: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html

The reason why you need to reduce features first is, is because your LOF will be much more stable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'll look into it. But there are no anomalies in the dataset, no "bad" data I can use for training. It's an incomplete dataset if you want to look at it this way. I want to "complete" it with bad data so that it will be able to distinguish good from bad, but I don't know if its a good idea.

Comment: You don't need to specify bad examples in LOF

Comment: That's the point of the algorithm, it models the distribution of normal data (think a field of RBFs), and then you can check if a new point fits in the distribution or not.